# User can has only one value for User Property?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

If I have user who likes apples and oranges can I code it like this:

```
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({favorite_food: 'apples'});
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({favorite_food: 'oranges'});
```

or I must create values like this:

```
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({favorite_food: 'apples_oranges'});
```

?
In Firebase docs I havent found information if some user has multi value for one User Property, their example: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=ios#set_user_properties_2](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties)
based on 1 value per 1 User Property, but what if 1 user has many values for 1 user property?

Answer (score 1):

A user property can hold a single value. Your first code sample would set the user property to "apples" and then set the same user property to "oranges".